# In java how can i extract string from response?

Tags: java

is there a way to extract string from this response ?

```
{"target":150740755136115,"placeholder_id":"postPlaceholder"}
```

I just need 150740755136115 please help

Comment: Search how to parse JSON in Java.

Comment: check this one ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core)

```
private class MyPOJO {
    public String target;
    @JsonProperty("placeholder_id")
    public String placeholder;

    public MyPOJO(String target, String placeholder) {
        this.target = target;
        this.placeholder = placeholder;
    }
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyPOJO data = mapper.readValue(yourJsonString, MyPOJO.class);

System.out.println(data.target);
```